# How to check .mp4 file is corrupted or not.

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

I am recording two different videos in the .mp4 format using ffmpeg command and after that combining them.

But sometimes one of the video is get corrupted because of that it will affecting on the combining process. So I have to add simple check for checking file is corrupted or not but I don't have any idea how to do it.

So is there any ffmpeg command or other command that checks that file is corrupted.
I have to do this from the command line.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 for this.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Please explain how you determine that the file is corrupted. Does it freeze during playback? Any visual errors? Or does the combining script fail? In the latter case, please show the actual error. Also include the ffmpeg command you use to record.

Comment: @slhck  When I play video, I am getting glitches, sometimes errors while playing such as "Can not play this video". Sometime video played without throwing any error but I can't see or hear anything. This is somewhat random corruption.

Comment: What is your full ffmpeg command and output?